# Centos7 password based Authentication failing

Tags: linux, ssh, active-directory, centos-7, sshd

Successfully joined AD server:

```
id user@example.local
```

Got the results so the user exists:
`ssh user@example.local@XXX.XX.XXX.XXX`

```
Error:  
debug3: send packet: type 50  
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply  
debug3: receive packet: type 51  
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password  
Permission denied, please try again.
```

error:

```
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key


vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

[image]
sudo systemctl restart sshd

I have also tried restarting sshd but no result.

Comment: Does `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key` exist?

Comment: No, but one of my server which is replica of this server also doesn't have the file you have mentioned but it is still working.

Comment: Since, it is AD integrated I don't think it is required.

Comment: Are you using realmd for AD integration? If so, what is the allowed user list look like when you run `realm list`?